# Referencing file in Django views.py

Tags: python, django, file

I am building a Django web interface (overkill - I know!) for a few small python functions. One of these transforms a txt file stored in Django root. Well it aims to.

I have the following setup in a few places:

```
with open('file.csv','r') as source:
...
```

However, without setting the entire directory on my machine (e.g. /home/...), it cannot find the file. I have tried putting this in the Static directory (as ideally I would like people to be able to download the file at a later stage) but same problem.

How do you work with files within Django? What is best practice to solve the above allowing someone to download it later?

Comment: If you want users download files later, you can store their paths in a model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need the path:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

file_path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'file.txt')

with open(file_path, 'r') as source:
    # do stuff
```

- Please notice that you need to put your file in a directory like this: my_app/static/my_app/file.txt

for more information you can refer to Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/).

Comment: Doing this, would I then be able to open it and use it?

Comment: Would one need to define static root each time the app is installed? I could only do this if I defined static root right to the app's static directory. So this would not work with multiple apps?

Comment: from the docs: Now we might be able to get away with putting our static files directly in my_app/static/ (rather than creating another my_app subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will use the first static file it finds whose name matches, and if you had a static file with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those static files inside another directory named for the application itself.

Comment: I understand that completely. However, I am referring more to the fact that I am unable to define multiple static_roots? Or do I just reference the root directory?

Comment: you just reference the root directory.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that.